# PDO не добавляются данные в БД

Tags: pdo, php

Код:

```
if ($result = $db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `vkid`=:vkid WHERE `login`=:name "))
{
    $vkid = $idv;
    $name = $_SESSION['login'];
    $result->bindParam(":vkid",$vkid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->bindParam(":name",$login,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
echo 'ID успешно привязан'; 
echo $vkid;
}
```

В итоге данные не обновляются. 
И хотелось бы узнать, как можно проверить, добавились данные иди нет

Comment: $name = $_SESSION['login'];

и смотрим сюда

$result->bindParam(":name",$login,PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: > PDOStatement::execute()  
> ... 
> **Возвращаемые значения**  
>  
> Возвращает TRUE в случае успешного завершения или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки.

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @rnddev - Вы божественны! 
А я пойду спать)